# I need a help in writing a function that counts the digits and letters separately then returns the result in a dictionary format

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have been working on the python challenge question and I have been stuck it on for a while. Below is the question.

Write a function that takes a string and calculates the number of letters and digits within it. Return the result in a dictionary.

Examples:

```
count_all("Hello World") ➞ { "LETTERS":  10, "DIGITS": 0 }

count_all("H3ll0 Wor1d") ➞ { "LETTERS":  7, "DIGITS": 3 }

count_all("149990") ➞ { "LETTERS": 0, "DIGITS": 6 }
```

Notes:

- Tests contain only alphanumeric characters.
- Spaces are not letters.
- All tests contain valid strings.
- The function should return dictionary

I have written a code to solve it but I have been getting a 'Too many positional arguments for function call.

```
def count_all(string):
 
    d = 0
    l = 0    
    for c in string:
        if c.isdigit():
            d=d+1
        elif c.isalpha():
            l=l+1
        else:
            pass


print(count_all("string", "l"))
print(count_all("string", "d"))
```

what have I done wrong exactly?

Comment: Please change the title of the post to reflect the underlying problem so that others can search for solutions later. Please treat stackoverflow as an encyclopaedia rather than a QA website like yahoo answers or quora.

Comment: How many parameters does your `def count_all` specify for your function? Now how many arguments are you trying to give when you call your function?

Comment: According to ***your*** definition function `count_all()` accepts a single parameter.  Inside your `print()` calls you pass two.

Comment: When you fix this problem, please note that your function is supposed to return a `dictionary`, but does not return anything at all.

Comment: so I should write return(dict(count_all("string", "l", "d"))) at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all you need to do is make it so that you're passing just 1 string to your function, like so: `print(count_all("letters and numbers 12345"))`. And second, you need to change the output so that it should return a dict, like so: `return {"letters": l, "digits": d}`.

Comment: should I just remove print and just write return {"letters": l, "digits": d}? Also remove pass?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
def countStuff(argString = None):
    resultDict = {"Letters" : 0, "Numbers" : 0}
    if argString is None:
        print("-_-")
    for i in argString:
        if i.isdigit():
            resultDict["Numbers"] += 1
        elif i.lower().islower():
            resultDict["Letters"] += 1
        else:
            pass
    print(resultDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphacount = 0
numcount = 0
str1 = input("Enter a sentence: ")
for x in str1:
    if x.isalpha():   # Check the Albhabets in String
        alphacount+=1       
    elif x.isdigit():   # Check the digits in String
        numcount+=1
    else:
        continue
        
print('LETTERS '+ str(alphacount))
print('DIGITS '+ str(numcount))
```

Comment: Surrounding your answer by some explanations would be a really nice thing.

Comment: Added. Hope this is helpful.